# C # How to get the picture from the structure obtained from the dll and save it locally

Tags: c#, c++

I have a dll file encapsulated in C++, this dll can extract text information and pictures.
When I use C++ to call the methods in this dll, there is no problem, I can extract information and save pictures.But when I use C# to call the method in the dll, the program can only extract the text and the picture fails.

My Code

## C++ code

### .h file

```cpp
//other code

typedef struct
{
char cEIDType[4];
char cEIDNumber[20];
char cEIDSide[2];
char cEIDSignCountry[4];
char cEIDChineseName[64];
char cEIDName[64];
char cEIDBirth[16];
char cEIDSex[4];
char cEIDNation[4];
char cEIDSignPlaceNo[8];
char cEIDValidDate[16];
int  iPhotoLen;
char cEIDPhoto[100*1024];
} cEIDCardInfo;

DLLEXPORT WORD __stdcall EID_ReadData(unsigned char *pIn,  cEIDCardInfo  *p_psCardInfo);

//other code
```

### cpp file

```cpp
cEIDCardInfo info;
int re = EID_ReadData(0,&info);

if(re == 1){
    unsigned char tmp[128];
    memset(tmp,0,128);
    memcpy(tmp,info.cEIDType,4);
    printf("cEIDType=%s\n",tmp);
    memset(tmp,0,128);
    memcpy(tmp,info.cEIDNumber,20);
    printf("cEIDNumber=%s\n",tmp);

    FILE *fp=fopen("head.jpg","wb");
    fwrite(info.cEIDPhoto,1,info.iPhotoLen,fp); // Will successfully print the text and save the picture locally

    fclose(fp);

}
```

## C# code

### struct file

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EidReaderFormApp.utils
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    struct PassportInfo
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
        public string cEIDType;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string cEIDNumber;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)]
        public string cEIDSide;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
        public string cEIDSignCountry;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        public string cEIDChineseName;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
        public string cEIDName;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string cEIDBirth;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
        public string cEIDSex;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)] 
        public string cEIDNation;


        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string cEIDSignPlaceNo;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string cEIDValidDate;

        public int iPhotoLen;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100 * 1024)]
        public string cEIDPhoto;
    }
}
```

### C# demo

```
 [DllImport(@"EID.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "EID_ReadData")]
 public static extern int ReadData(StringBuilder pInput, IntPtr pOut);

//other code

void GetData(){
    IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PassportInfo)));

    int code = ReadData(new StringBuilder(0), intPtr);

    if(code == 1)
    {
        PassportInfo passportInfo = (PassportInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(intPtr , typeof(PassportInfo));

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("clk.png", FileMode.Create);

        fileStream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(passportInfo.cEIDPhoto),0, passportInfo.iPhotoLen); //System.ArgumentException => Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection

        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In c# signature of `ReadData` looks wrong and you are not calling it anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a struct pointer as a parameter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297598/passing-a-struct-pointer-as-a-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

fixed

change

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100 * 1024)]
public byte[] cEIDPhoto;
```